# Different realizations of single-electron double-slit experiment

Tags: double-slit-experiment, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

Recently I was reading about the real world realization of the double-slit experiment, in which we shoot single electrons. The final detection on the rear screen is done "by collecting the transmitted electrons with a single-electron detector". Of course the electron build up over time looks like this:

[image]

Is there some version of this experiment, in which these single-electron detectors are replaced with something "simpler". Or rather than that, what is the simplest possible "device", that would force the shooted particle to colapse in some place on the screen, giving the interference pattern?

Could a simple "wall" or some potential barrier force such an electron (or some other particle) to collapse?

Comment: It never occurred to me that a "single-electron detector" need be anything much more complicated than a photographic plate! It is simply a wall or potential barrier, but one which keeps a record of where the electron landed.

Comment: So just to be sure, in a theoretical description of this process a simple wall or a potential barrier would force the electron to collapse?

Comment: Just so long as there is, at least in principle, a mechanism to detect where the electron landed, the wave function will collapse

Comment: Electrons do not collapse at some place on the screen. They are fired along some trajectory, travel through a slit and eventually reach a point on the screen.